Moving to EU as a dual UK/Irish citizen with a dual NZ/Canadian Partner
my partner and I are wanting to move to Europe next year for a year or so to live and work. I have a Uk and Irish passport and he has a New Zealand and Canadian passport. We have been living in NZ for the last 5 years. We are not sure what country we will live in yet so cannot apply for the correct countries visa from NZ. With my Irish passport I can live and work anywhere in the EU but I can’t seem to find and easy option for him to do the same. Does anyone know if this is possible? Like a generic EU partner visa type thing. An Irish visa requires us to be living and working in Ireland which we don’t plan to do. Thanks in advance 


but I can’t seem to find and easy option for him to do the same

If you are married or in a formally registered partnership then your partner has this right automatically.  If your partnership is not formally registered then it still may be possible but it will depend on the authorities of the country you go to recognizing that yours is a "durable relationship," which you will have to prove to them, and the availability of this option is not clear to me in several countries, notably including Germany.
A visa is required only for those who require a visa to visit as a tourist.  Since both Canadian and New Zealand citizens are visa-exempt, no visa is necessary in this case.
The country you move to can require your partner to register, but the deadline for doing so cannot be sooner than three months after arrival.  Most countries require registration, and most have set the deadline at the three-month minimum.
